# Examples of self-saturated Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is called self-saturated if every infinite dimensional subspace of it contains a further subspace isomorphic to $X$. Some classical examples of such spaces    are $c_0$ and $\ell_p$-spaces for $1\leq p<\infty$ (Pelczynski, 1960).

Are there any other known examples of self-saturated spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-saturated Banach space is called *minimal*. There is now whole industry for such spaces, however using $\ell_p$ and $c_0$ you may produce some trivial examples by passing to subspaces of these spaces. Thus, for example $c_0$-sums of finite-dimensional Banach spaces are minimal as they always embed into $c_0$.

The most prominent, non-classical example is [Schlumprecht's space](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~denka/ttt-pklin.pdf).